# Use Raspberry Pi 3B+ to read sensor data from Arduino Uno with JDY-18 bluetooth module

Tags: python, arduino, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, sensors

I Used Rpi 3B+ to read sensor data from Arduino Uno with JDY-18 bluetooth module. JDY-18 can connect to Rpi, but can't receive sensor data.

My Arduino code like this :

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "LowPower.h" // For Arduino Sleep Mode

SoftwareSerial BTSerial(2, 3); // RX | TX

int soilMoisureInt;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(A0, INPUT);
  BTSerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  // Make initial soilMoisureInt equal zero
  soilMoisureInt = analogRead(A0);

  // Send data through bluetooth
  BTSerial.write(soilMoisureInt);

  // Get Arduino into sleep mode
  for (int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
    LowPower.powerDown(SLEEP_4S, ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF);
}
```

And my Rpi code like this (use bluepy Python3 package):

```
import bluepy.btle as btle

# Set up variables
dataInt = None
blue_address = "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"

# For bluepy Peripheral class
class ReadDelegate(btle.DefaultDelegate):
    def handleNotification(self, cHandle, data):
        # Access global variables insid class
        global dataInt
        # Change ascii char to int
        dataInt = ord(data)

# Connect to bluetooth module
p = btle.Peripheral(blue_address)
# Use ReadDelegate
p.withDelegate(ReadDelegate())

# Read date
while True:
    p.waitForNotifications(0)
    print("Soil Moisure : " + str(dataInt))
```

Could anyone have the experience of connection between JDY-18 and Rpi?

Comment: I would suggest using generic Bluetooth Low Energy scanning and exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to find the Service and Characteristic UUIDs for the JDY-18 device. You can also check that notifications are enabled.

Comment: I used app to find JDY-18 module service and characteristic. I only found Write, Notify , and WriteWithoutResponse properties(the notifications are enabled), but no read property. Does it lead to Rpi can't read sensor data from JDY-18? Thx.

Comment: `Notify` is fairly typical for sensors as you only want Bluetooth Low Energy sensor to turn on its radio and send data when it has got something to send. Are you seeing the sensor value update in nRF Connect with notifications on?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, the value below primary service is updated with time.

Comment: Comment `p.withDelegate(ReadDelegate())`. Then add `p.getServices()` and `getCharacteristics()` and update your question please with the output of these two.